# Como criar divs dentro do javaScript e utilizar Json

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Estou tentado criar e preencher vários cards html de acordo com o retorno Json que tenho de um arquivo PHP, tenho o Javascript que pega o array Json, minha duvida é como faço para criar vários cards dentro desse javascript ?

Javascript

```
 $(function(){
    carregar(0,12,'Chamadas/testeCarregarAnuncios.php');
    $("#carregarMais").click(function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        var init = $().length;
        carregar(init, 12, 'Chamadas/testeCarregarAnuncios.php');
    });
    function carregar(init, max, url){
        var dados = {init: init, max : max};
        $.post(url, dados, function(data){
          for(i = 0; i < data.dados.length; i++){ 

         }
         var anunciosExibidos = $("").length;
         if(anunciosExibidos== data.totalAnuncios)
         {
             $("#carregarMais").hide();
         }
        },"json");
    }
});
```

Card HTML que preciso criar para cara retorno json

```
<a style="display: block; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);" href="#">
                        <div style="box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 6px;">  
                            <div class="col s4 m4" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
                                <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                                    <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; right: -50%;">
                                        <img src="img/hardware2.jpg" alt="user background" style="height: 150px; width: auto; position: relative; left: -50%; vertical-align: bottom;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col s8 m8 truncate-text" style="padding-left: 14px; padding-top: 8px; height: 150px;">
                                    <span class="grey-text text-darken-4" style="font-size: 20px;"></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="grey-text"></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="star-result" style="margin-bottom: -10px;">
                                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                                        <style>
                                            .checked {
                                                color: orange;
                                            }
                                        </style>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <i class="mdi-image-navigate-next cyan-text text-darken-2"></i>
                                    <span class="cyan-text text-darken-2">Informática</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <i class="mdi-communication-location-on cyan-text text-darken-2"></i> 
                                    <span class="cyan-text text-darken-2"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
```

devo criar linha a linha do card dentro do Javascript ? tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: Eu to aprendendo a usar o vue.js e acho que seria muito util pra você. Para o que você quer fazer acho que seria uma otima solução, pq vc pode fazer um modelo de card onde vai receber os dados e o vue.js duplica os cards de acordo com os registros em JSON.  o site do https://vuejs.org/ pra vc conhecer melhor

Answer (score -1):

Olha como eu respondi no comentário da pergunta, acho que o vue.js seria bem melhor para você.

Aqui eu dou um exemplo bem fácil de como usar.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#v-for-cards',
  data: {
     itens: [{"titulo":"Titulo do card 1", "descricao":"Descrição de teste"},{"titulo": "Titulo do Card 2", "descricao":"mais um teste"}]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="v-for-cards">
      <div v-for="(item, keyitem) in itens">
           <h1> Titulo: {{ item.titulo }} </h1>
           <p> {{ item.descricao }}</p>
           <hr>
       </div>
</div>
```