# Como acessar os elementos de uma String no formato Jason no JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Não consigo imprimir os valores contidos em uma string no formato Jason usando JavaScript em um modal contendo várias listas de definição. Imagino que seja algum erro de sintaxe no acesso mas não consegui resolver.

O meu cenário aqui é o seguinte.

Aqui após efetuar a consulta ao banco de Dados, faço a conversão através de PHP da variável **$found** para uma string no formato Jason da seguinte forma:

```js
$veiculo_string_jason = json_encode($found);
echo $veiculo_string_jason;
```

O conteúdo da variável **$veiculo_string_jason** é o seguinte:

```js
{"tipo":"Carro","marca":"Citroen","modelo":"Air Cross Salomon Exclusive 1.6 Flex","alimentacao":"Flex","placa":"ABC1234","cor":"Branco","anofab":"2014","anomod":"2015","chassi":"11111111111111111","renavam":"22222222222","valor_compra":"42000.00","valor_venda":"45500.00","situacao":"Consignado","status":"Ativo"}
```

O código JavaScript que faz a interface toda é esse aqui:

```js
// INTERFACE MODAL viewVeiculo
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function () {
        var placa = null;
        placa = $(this).attr("placa");
        if (placa !== '') {
            var dados = {
                placa: placa
            };
            $.post('dsVeiculo.php', dados, function (retorna) {
                var veiculo = retorna;
                $("#var0").html(veiculo.tipo);
                $("#var1").html(veiculo.marca);
                $("#var2").html(veiculo.modelo);
                $("#var3").html(veiculo.alimentacao);
                $("#var4").html(veiculo.placa);
                $("#var5").html(veiculo.cor);
                $("#var6").html(veiculo.anofab);
                $("#var7").html(veiculo.anomod);
                $("#var8").html(veiculo.chassi);
                $("#var9").html(veiculo.renavam);
                $("#var10").html(veiculo.valor_compra);
                $("#var11").html(veiculo.valor_venda);
                $("#var12").html(veiculo.situacao);
                $("#var13").html(veiculo.status);
                $('#viewVeiculo').modal('show');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Os ID's de #var0 até #var13 são listas de definição.

```html
<dl class="row mb-0">
  <dt class="col-sm-6 text-right">Tipo:</dt>
  <dd id="var0" class="col-sm-6"></dd>
</dl>
```

Busquei ajuda nesses tópicos mas sem sucesso.

[Como mostrar os valores armazenados no JSON em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54524/como-mostrar-os-valores-armazenados-no-json-em-javascript)

[Como criar divs dentro do javaScript e utilizar Json](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337198/como-criar-divs-dentro-do-javascript-e-utilizar-json)

Comment: Você precisa dar um parse na response. `var veiculo = jQuery.parseJSON( retorna );`

Comment: @IgorMello fiz a correção e deu certo, agora consigo acessar cada elemento da string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A formatação do JSON está certa, alias, se passou pela função `json_encode` não tem como estar errada.

A razão pela qual você não está conseguindo ler as propriedades desse JSON no lado do usuário é provavelmente porque o seu usuário não sabe que o servidor está retornando um JSON, ele acha que o servidor está retornando um texto qualquer.

Você pode fazer um `console.log` nesse `retorna` para verificar se essa variável realmente contém um objeto, ou uma string.

Agora para fazer o parse dessa string para JSON, você tem algumas opções, como:

1- faça o parse manualmente no lado do usuário

```
var veiculo = JSON.parse(retorna);
```

2- no PHP, inclua o `header` com o tipo do conteúdo que você está retornando, dessa forma o `jQuery` fará o parse automaticamente

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

3- inclua o tipo do retorno na própria chamada do AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'dsVeiculo',
    method: 'POST'
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(retorna) {
      // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: fiz a correção e deu certo, agora consigo acessar cada elemento da string.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu passar um objeto ao invés de uma string, como eu faria o acesso aos dados?

O objeto tem essa estrutura:

```js
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'tipo' => string 'Carro' (length=5)
  public 'marca' => string 'Citroen' (length=8)
  public 'modelo' => string 'Air Cross Salomon Exclusive 1.6 Flex' (length=36)
  public 'alimentacao' => string 'Flex' (length=6)
  public 'placa' => string 'ABC1234' (length=7)
  public 'cor' => string 'Branco' (length=4)
  public 'anofab' => string '2014' (length=4)
  public 'anomod' => string '2015' (length=4)
  public 'chassi' => string '11111111111111111' (length=17)
  public 'renavam' => string '22222222222' (length=11)
  public 'valor_compra' => string '42000.00' (length=8)
  public 'valor_venda' => string '45000.00' (length=8)
  public 'situacao' => string 'Consignado' (length=10)
  public 'status' => string 'Ativo' (length=5)
```